# Can I build all ideology wonders in my original capital in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

Can I somehow build all ideology wonders ( Statue of Liberty, Prora and Kremlin ) into my original capital in Civilization 5? I understand that I need two revolutions to change the ideology twice but I am wondering whether or not that would work in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, yes. However, they are all world wonders, so there is a good chance someone else will build one of them before you have switched twice.

But it is possible, as stated by the person in this link:
https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/is-it-possible-to-switch-ideologies-for-the-purpose-of-wonder-building.520949/